# Postgres query on multi column unique index takes longer than expected

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a large table with 2 columns:

```
name::text
url::text
```

I have indices on both columns and I have another unique index on `(name, url`). When I execute

```
select count(*) from t where name = 'foo'
```

and

```
select count(*) from t where url = 'bar'
```

it takes 14 seconds and 27 milli seconds, respectively. But when I execute a combined query

```
select count(*) from t where url = 'bar' and name = 'foo'
```

it takes 84 seconds. Isn't it supposed to take around 27 milli seconds or I'm missing something?

EDIT:

Here is the output of explain:

```
Aggregate  (cost=5.77..5.78 rows=1 width=0)
    ->  Index Scan using ix_t_name on t  (cost=0.56..5.76 rows=1 width=0)
        Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'foo'::text)
        Filter: ((url)::text = 'bar'::text)"
```

EDIT:

And here is the output of `explain analyze`:

```
Aggregate  (cost=5.77..5.78 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=402957.433..402957.433 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using ix_t_name on t  (cost=0.56..5.76 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1.635..402957.429 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'foo'::text)
        Filter: ((url)::text = 'bar'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 286544
Total runtime: 402957.490 ms
```

Comment: Do an EXPLAIN of your select to verify that postgres is using the index. Also if your index is `name, url` then maybe helps if you `where` clause is `name = 'foo'  and url = 'bar'`

Comment: @Aguardientico I added the explain output.

Comment: btw, I swapped the conditions and explain's output is the same.

Comment: @AliBZ In that explain, you see a crucial fact: Postgres is *not* choosing your combined index, it's choosing the index on `name`, and filtering the results by `url`.

Comment: Here's a good series of blog posts on understanding `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output: http://www.depesz.com/2013/04/16/explaining-the-unexplainable/ In this case, it appears that Postgres's statistics (*wrongly*) led it to think it would have very few rows matching `name =  'foo'`, so the extra filter on `url = 'bar'` would be very quick.

Comment: Postgres try to use the best option to lookup the info, it looks something weird in the explain, It saids that only found 1 row for your where, maybe if you use a real info for you explain instead of foo and bar it will help to verify the "why". BTW: Give a look to this page http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-examine.html to get some tips about how to verify index use

Comment: @Aguardientico I am using real values, I changed them on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please re-run with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` instead of `EXPLAIN`; that will actually run the query, and show you the difference between what Postgres *expected* to happen, and what it *actually* found when it looked at the data. And [there's some hints here about what to include in PostgreSQL Performance questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: And run `vacuum analyze <tblname>` ; at least after you added/updated/deleted data or added indices.

Comment: @IMSoP I added the output of `explain analyze`.

Comment: And the cardinality (or entropy, if you want)  of the `name` and `url` columns is?

Comment: @wildplasser sorry, I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @AliBZ how many (in percentage) different values are in `name` and `url` columns. Please run `vacuum analyze` as it was suggested though.

Comment: urls are almost unique, names are from a limited list of 20. I have around 20M records in total.

Comment: It is a measure for the amount of specificity for the {name,url} fields. Number of distinct values. Are the specified values you search for very rare, or very common?

Comment: There you go. For the time being: increase your statistic targets ( := size of the histobram) 1/20 is a borderline case (assuming equal distribution) .

Comment: @wildplasser that's curious that postgresql cannot determine that on default settings. 20 out of 20M is not some exotic case (or is it).

Comment: @wildplasser I vacuumed the table and now it takes 17ms! Could you please add an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Any chance you have autovacuum routines disabled? It's strange that after inserting 20M of rows it was not triggered.

Comment: I've never changed vacuum settings. I'll check if its enabled or not.

Comment: @zerkms last autovacuum date is last month. But thats right after I inserted the data. So, it looks like autovacuum did its job.

Comment: Which Postgres version? below 8.4 ? (8.3 had no autovacuum enabled by default settings)

Comment: I have postgres 9.3.